# Set an action for a teacup styled button in ruby motion

Tags: rubymotion

if i am creating my button in my pro-motion screen:

```
add button = UIButton.new,
  stylename: :my_button,            # Teacup
  resize: [ :left, :right, :top ], # ProMotion
  frame: CGRectMake(25, 250, 90, 90)
```

How can I add an action to my button?

The action should look something like this:

```
addTarget(self, action: :an_action,
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
button = add UIButton.new, {
  stylename: :my_button,            # Teacup
  resize: [ :left, :right, :top ], # ProMotion
  frame: CGRectMake(25, 250, 90, 90),
  :"addTarget:action:forControlEvents:" => [ self, :an_action, UIControlEventTouchUpInside ]
}
```

You can just pass in an array and the `add` method will splat it into args. It's essentially the same as:

```
send(:"addTarget:action:forControlEvents:", self, :an_action, UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
```

By the way, you need to put the `add` call on the other side of the assign, since the hash is the second argument of the `add` method.

Comment: thanks.  this got me past the block although i have since started playing with promotion with pixate, which seems a good mix.

Comment: Yes, ProMotion's styling syntax is for simple apps. If you want more power, try Pixate, Teacup, and/or RMQ. Motion-layout is another option.

Comment: the amount of choice in the RM world is mindblowing considering how new the technology is.